# Dragging and dropping tags doesn't work

Tags: support, tags

I saw that the `RELATED TAGS` section allowed drag and drop... so I dropped one into the add to favorites box and clicked `Add`. now the incredibly long uri is in my interesting tags section and the overflow setting is such that the remove link is not visible. Checked against `IE 7.0.5730.13` and `Chrome 10.0.648.151`

The interesting tag link points to `http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpgaming.stackexchange.comquestionstaggedworld-of-warcraft`

Answer (score 2):

I have gone and removed that tag from your profile on Gaming. Is that the only place it was on?

In the process, it may have cleared one additional tag from your preferences, so in advance, I'm sorry if it had. Please make sure your other preferences are correct, and add the missing one if I had caught one.

I'm not sure that tags are supposed to be drag-and-dropped to add them into your preferences. But a shortcut over typing them, provided you don't mind email reminders, is that the tag-popup when hovering over a tag can be used to add to your favorites by clicking the "subscribe" option in the top right.

Comment: Thanks, is this the right place to report it so it can be looked at and fixed for the community of exchange sites?

Comment: @Maslow Honestly, I haven't even been able to reproduce your issue, I cannot drag-and-drop from the related tags section (IE8/XP). This leads me to believe this was less of a feature of Stack Exchange, and more some function that your browser allowed instead.

Comment: @Grace ah, so chrome let me drop it, but neither IE or chrome could display the remove link. Do I accept the answer or wait for someone that would look at this as a possible css/display bug?

Comment: @Maslow I see balpha and a couple other devs wandering about. One of them might comment on it. If anything, even if there isn't necessarily a bug considered with the drag-and-drop, there may be something else like say tag-is-way-too-long, since normally there's a 25 character limit on tags.

Comment: Being able to drag-and-drop a url into a text box isn't a browser problem. The problem is that you can't remove a tag that's really long from your interesting tags, or that it lets you put one that long in.

Comment: @Grace agreed, I know better, but I imagine it's extra cruft to have posts like this one or emails or what have you assuming I'm not the only one on a stack exchange site that has or will make this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

No, the tag area does not allow drag and drop. That's just the default behaviour of dragging and dropping links; it just copies the destination URL in the dropped-upon textbox.